# Modified SRPM conflict resolution

Tags: redhat, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I need to update libvncserver and libvncclient libraries to 0.9.11. 
I am running CentOS 7.3, currently, the latest libvncserver RPM is 0.9.9

So I took the libvncserver SRPM, modified the spec file, and updated the libvncserver tarball to create a 0.9.11 version of libvncserver and libvncclient RPM's.

I'm having a dependency challenge upon install.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining ../RPMS/x86_64/libvncserver-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm: libvncserver-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64
Marking ../RPMS/x86_64/libvncserver-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm as an update to libvncserver-0.9.9-9.el7_0.1.x86_64
Examining ../RPMS/x86_64/libvncserver-debuginfo-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm: libvncserver-debuginfo-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64
Marking ../RPMS/x86_64/libvncserver-debuginfo-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining ../RPMS/x86_64/libvncserver-devel-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm: libvncserver-devel-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64
Marking ../RPMS/x86_64/libvncserver-devel-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libvncserver.x86_64 0:0.9.9-9.el7_0.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libvncclient.so.0()(64bit) for package: x11vnc-0.9.13-11.el7.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
--> Processing Dependency: libvncserver.so.0()(64bit) for package: x11vnc-0.9.13-11.el7.x86_64
---> Package libvncserver.x86_64 0:0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1 will be an update
---> Package libvncserver-debuginfo.x86_64 0:0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1 will be installed
---> Package libvncserver-devel.x86_64 0:0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: x11vnc-0.9.13-11.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: libvncclient.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: libvncserver-0.9.9-9.el7_0.1.x86_64 (@base)
               libvncclient.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: libvncserver-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (/libvncserver-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64)
              ~libvncclient.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: x11vnc-0.9.13-11.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: libvncserver.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: libvncserver-0.9.9-9.el7_0.1.x86_64 (@base)
               libvncserver.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: libvncserver-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (/libvncserver-0.9.11-1.el7.centos.1.x86_64)
              ~libvncserver.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

x11vnc is using libvncserver.so.0 and libvncclient.so.0 from 0.9.9

```
[localhost SPECS]$ sudo ldd /usr/bin/x11vnc | grep -i vnc
        libvncserver.so.0 => /lib64/libvncserver.so.0 (0x00007fee9387d000)
        libvncclient.so.0 => /lib64/libvncclient.so.0 (0x00007fee9365f000)
```

Running the above in verbose, rpm tries to update x11vnc (to there is none)

```
Potential Provider: libvncserver.x86_64 0:0.9.9-9.el7_0.1
Mode is ud for provider of libvncserver.so.0()(64bit): libvncserver.x86_64 0:0.9.9-9.el7_0.1
Mode for pkg providing libvncserver.so.0()(64bit): ud
Trying to update x11vnc-0.9.13-11.el7.x86_64 to resolve dep
No update paths found for x11vnc-0.9.13-11.el7.x86_64. Failure!
Searching pkgSack for dep: libvncserver.so.0()(64bit)
```

I could "force-install" but before I do so I'm interested is there a better way to do this? Is it possible to specify dependency checker to not highlight the dependency? Another approach is to create a custom x11vnc RPM, just to update the library path.

Comment: Don't replace system libraries. Rename your new RPM and put them somewhere else, like `/usr/local/lib`. See also https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines?rd=Packaging/Guidelines#Bundling_and_Duplication_of_system_libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your package does not provide `libvncserver.so.0`, but replaces `libvncserver`, which provides `libvncserver.so.0`.  The easiest solution is to rename your package, so that it can be installed along with the existing `libvncserver` package.

The `-devel` subpackage will probably have to conflict with `libvncserver-devel` because some of the files will overlap, but for the main package, you should be able to enable parallel installation.

You already mentioned the other clean solution: Port all packages from `libvncserver.so.0` to `libvncserver.so.1`. But that could involve quite a bit of unnecessary work and makes your system less similar to others.

(You could also keep the `libvncserver` package name and create a `compat-libvncserver` package with the old library, but that's again quite a bit of work for very little benefit.)

Comment: It seems creating a package of a different name is the best approach. Particularly if CentOS updates libvncserver in the future, yum update would install theirs and and supersedes my hacked rpm.